# How to reverse the travel to an craftsman garage door opener model 139.57918 1 HP

Tags: garage-door-opener

I install the Craftsman garage door opener and is working fine except by the thing that when the garage opener “Open/Up” it close my gate and Vice-versa.

This cause to me a security malfunction with the sensor because when is triggered the gate will close.

Also i try to move the travel when is already set, but i can’t fine tuning it.  So the garage opener close securely and if i try to reset the travel limits it became with same condition of when the door opener is Open/Up the gate close.

Also at craftsman told me that the travel mechanism quick release cable should point to the motor and is installed that way

What i can do to correct the situation or problem.

Thanks

Comment: All the garage door openers I've ever used respond to the press of a single button by changing direction. They're really not concerned with what is "up" or "down", "open" or "closed". Does your opener have two buttons with labels, one for "open" and one for "close"? If so, can you use a label maker (or just a piece of masking tape) to switch the labeling?

Comment: If you can't do that, you'd need to switch the way the opener is mounted or the way it's connected to the gate. If you would [edit] your post to include a nice overview picture of the gate and opener, then maybe a closer, more detailed picture of the mounting, that would probably help.

Comment: Is this on a *garage door*, or on a *gate* of some sort?

Comment: @FreeMan all you had to do was Google the model and you would know this has UP and DOWN buttons.   https://i.sears.com/s/d/pdf/mp-tc/10022781/prod_17764950812  .

Comment: Sure looks like you wired something backwards, or are misreading the Owner's Manual as to which is the UP and which is the DOWN control button.